# Given sequence S and T, find a sequence X and Y such that S and T belong to the shuffle of X and Y. (X and Y may not exist)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic, dynamic-programming, genetic-algorithm

I have to make a dynamic programming algorithm that solve this problem : Given sequence S and T, find a sequence X and Y  such that S and T belong to the shuffle of X and Y.

Sequence S and T are given with each having length n .
We want to find a sequence X and a sequence Y each of length k an l such that S and T belong to the shuffle product of X and Y. Knowing that (k+l = n)

How to I go about solving this using dynamic programming. I'm interested in knowing what could be the policy for using past results. As of now I have no idea.

Can someone do an example with S = GTACA and T = AGCAT
Let's assume that my table looks like this:

[image: empty table]

We want the green cell to provide sequence X and Y or provide nothing (In the case X and Y don't exist)

[image: selection of past solutions]

I have noticed that in many dynamic programming problems the past solution for building the current one is selected from either the cell at the left (red) or top (yellow) or diagonal (blue) of the current cell (outline in green). I still struggle to know how to select given my specific problem.

**UPDATE**

When I try to find the longest common subsequence as suggested by the answer below I get AGCA  following this (from the wikipedia article suggested below.)
[image: from the wikipedia articles]

My dynamic programming table looks like this:
[image: my table]

If I made a mistake please tell me where so I can correct it.

Comment: Why did you delete your old question and re-post? The sequence lengths you post here don't make sense.

Comment: Why does it not make sense?

Comment: Cause a shuffle of `X` and `Y` each of length `k+l` would have strings of lengths `2k + 2l`, whereas the inputs strings are of length `k` and `l`. The question you posted first made perfect sense, on the other hand.

Comment: Sorry I messed up. I corrected it in the question. It's X and Y who are of length n each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the [Longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) in disguise: Given S and T you find the longest common subsequence. That would be X. The left out elements would be the sequence Y if they appear in the same order in S and T, or they indicate that no such X and Y exist if they don't appear in the same order.

In your example the longest common subsequence is `ACA`. Therefore X = `ACA` and the left out elements in S and T are `GT`, appearing in the same order in both. Consequently Y = `GT`.

**EDIT:** Your dynamic programming table is incorrect. For example in the 3rd row and 4th column the cell should have the two sequences `A` and `G`, not a single sequence `AG`. To quote from Wikipedia:

> If they are not equal, then the longer of the two sequences [...] is retained. (If they are the same length, but not identical, then both are retained.)

Here is the full table (sans empty sequences):

```
  | G   T    A       C             A
-------------------------------------------
A |          A       A             A
G | G   G    A,G     A,G           A,G 
C | G   G    A,G     AC,GC         AC,GC
A | G   G    GA      AC,GA,GC      ACA,GCA
T | G   GT   GA,GT   AC,GA,GC,GT   ACA,GCA
```

This gives us two solutions for X, but only one of them gives us a valid Y:

- If X = `ACA` then Y = `GT` based on both S and T -- valid solution.
- If X = `GCA` then Y = `TA` based on S but `AT` based on T -- so this is not a solution.

I acknowledge that the above answer is not a complete solution to the problem. By the reasoning I gave in my comment below it follows only that X or Y are subsequences of the LCS. What subsequence is that still needs to be somehow determined.

Comment: Why is it the common longest subsequence problem? S = GTACA and T= AGCAT have the same letters but in different order. Should the longest common subsequence be themselves already. Why is it `ACA` ? Maybe it's `ACGA` right before having all the letters and therefore stopped being considered as a sub-sequence?

Comment: @Nassims: Please familiarize yourself with the LCS problem. `ACGA` is not a subsequence of either `GTACA` nor `AGCAT`. The reason it's LCS is because X (and Y) must both be sub-sequences of S and T (by the virtue of construction). Therefore the LCS of S and T will contain the longest of X or Y.

Comment: I have familiarize myself with the LCS problem however when I try doing the dynamic table I find AGCA. Maybe it's a mistake on my part, I would like to know where? (I have updated the question with images of my table and the function I followed in the wikipedia article.)

Comment: Thank you for the edit it adds much needed clarity.

Comment: Why is "If X = GCA then Y = TA based on S but AT based on T -- so this is not a solution." not a solution?

Comment: @Nassims: Y is the sequence that's left when you remove X from S and T. By the statement of the problem it should be the same for S and T. For X = `GCA` we get different Y based on S and T.